# Using Generics with DisplayArray method in WindowsForm

Tags: arrays, winforms, generics, display

I created a button in Windows Forms labeled Generics. When the button is clicked I want the array to display. I was able to execute in a standard .net application, but when trying to produce in windows forms only the message is displaying. How can I get the message to display and show the array?

```
 private void btnGeneric_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int[] intArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
            char[] charArray = { 'C', 'h', 'a', 'r', ' ', 'A', 'r', 'r', 'a', 'y' };
            String D1;

            MessageBox.Show("Array intArray Contains: ");
            DisplayArray(intArray);
            MessageBox.Show("Array charArray Contains: ");
            DisplayArray(charArray);


        }
        private static void DisplayArray<T>(T[] inputArray)
        {
            foreach (T element in inputArray)
                Console.Write(element + "");
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
        }
```

Comment: You only show "Array intArray Contains" in a message box. Then you call `DisplayArray` method which writes the array's content to the console. So what did you expect and what is the question? Are you asking how to concat the array elements into a string to show in the message box?

Comment: Yes I want to display all in the message.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to create a `string` from the array content and show that string in a message box.
So here is how it can be done:

```
private void btnGeneric_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int[] intArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    char[] charArray = { 'C', 'h', 'a', 'r', ' ', 'A', 'r', 'r', 'a', 'y' };

    string message = "Array intArray Contains: ";
    message += string.Join(string.Empty, intArray); 
    MessageBox.Show(message);

    message = "Array charArray Contains: ";
    message += string.Join(string.Empty, charArray);
    MessageBox.Show(message);
}
```

[`string.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Join__1_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) is a generic method to concat elements of a generic enumeration into a string.

So you could also modify your `DisplayArray` method to work like that:

```
public static string DisplayArray<T>(T[] array]) => string.Join(string.Empty, array);
```

Comment: Or `string.Concat()`, here.